# PHP with multiple statement/option doesnt work

Tags: php

```
if ( $new_status != 'publish' || $old_status == 'publish' || $post->post_type != 'movies', 'tvshows', 'episodes')
    return;
```

i want to have multiple option to trigger the script,

```php
$post->post_type != 'movies', 'tvshows', 'episodes'
```

this for example or even this

```php
$post->post_type != 'movies, tvshows, episodes'
```

none of these are working, anyone can help me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use extra pair of parentheses for this in combination with or-operator:

```php
if ($new_status != 'publish' || $old_status == 'publish' || $post->post_type != ('movies' || 'tvshows' || 'episodes'))
    return;
```